# rig animation actions for large number of copies but with time offset between copies in blender 3.x

Tags: animation, node-editor, armature, collections

Helo, Is there a way to create an army (for ex. 100) of RIG animated objects from the same mesh+armature and run a same action on the time line with time offset between all of the copies so they dont make the action in synchronization ? For exemple make them walk but not in the same rythm. I thing animation node was a solution but it is no more in blender 3.x ?

Comment: [Here's](https://youtu.be/xWq-ZPMhai8) one of Ian Hubert's one minute tutorials which might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you ; this is good advise and helped me clearly.